# Why do I get a blank permissions prompt when installing my app from the Play Store?

Tags: android, android-permissions

I've developed an app for Android and come across a bit of a strange issue. When installing my app from the Play Store, it brings up a permissions prompt, but then goes on to explain that my app doesn't actually require any special permissions.

I've tried installing other apps from the store and they install without the permissions prompt. So, I'm concerned that this is putting people off downloading my app.

Here's what the prompt looks like:

[image: Blank permissions issue]

I've never seen this for another app.

Here's my manifest file: https://gist.github.com/jdmunro/72375732203091041cf406b49c28f51b

App is built with SDK version 23 and supports a minimum of version 16. Does anyone know what might be causing this?

Comment: could be a bug due to `tools:node="remove"`

Comment: Hmm, I had similar thoughts. I have to do this because some third-party libraries are not declaring minSdkVersion and so it automatically adds permissions that I don't need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by setting the `targetSdkVersion` to 23 or higher.